# Change data type varchar to timestamp along with null values in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, casting, timestamp, type-conversion, varchar

Change data type **varchar to timestamp** along with **null values** in PostgreSQL
I have a column with empty rows and few with timestamp rows. How to convert that into timestamp data type in PostgreSQL?

Comment: Do you need to alter that column's data type to timestamp ?

Comment: show a sample data in that column,You need to provide more info.

Comment: what did you try? did you get any errors?

Answer (score 0):

You need a `USING` clause to turn the empty strings into `null`.

```
ALTER TABLE ... 
  ALTER COLUMN mycol 
    TYPE timestamp 
    USING (...conversion expression...)
```

Without seeing the input data it's hard to say exactly what that expression must be, but it probably involves `nullif` or `case` expressions and the `to_timestamp` function and/or a `CAST` to `timestamp`.